# How to set up/host a website on windows SERVER 2008

Tags: hosting, web-hosting

I Have all the hosting details and Domain specifications, I have logged into ftp using ftp details now where to upload the files of my website to make it work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a domain name and FTP details, sounds like you're using shared hosting. In that case, often the FTP directory will have "httpdocs" in it or "wwwroot", or maybe even "public_html". You place a file there and it should be accessible through the domain. Of course it might also be the case that you will need to change your nameservers on the domain to the nameservers that the hosting company provided.

Whenever I work with a new hosting company, I always do a test with a simple "test.jpg" (no scripting, no PHP, no ASP, etc). Once that works through the URL that I expect, I start more complicated tests.

Comment: this sounds more helping

Answer (score 3):

Generally in `C:\inetpub\wwwroot\`.  However, I highly suggest you research a lot more on the topic if you're going to be managing a web server.

Comment: I have windows 2008 server to host my web site in which folder i have to upload my file?

Comment: @OM The Eternity: As I mentioned, `C:\inetpub\wwwroot\` is the standard default web root for a Windows 2008 IIS instance (I'm assuming IIS since you didn't specify otherwise).  But be aware that there's a lot more that goes into setting up and maintaining a web server than just putting files somewhere.  The security implications of running a public server can't be understated.

Answer (score 2):

You should become familiar with IIS and IIS management.  In windows server 2008, You can use Server Manager to add the IIS Web Server role if it doesn't already exist.  Then you should expand Roles and Web Server (IIS) to reveal "Internet Information Services (IIS) Manager".  That is where you set up the web server.  Explore the menus there, they provide options you will need.  Enjoy!